Is translation from English necessary for Spanish short-stay Schengen visas?
I'm applying for a Schengen tourist visa (Spain), and I'm wondering if documents in English should be sworn and translated into Spanish. I know that it's required for national visa application documents to be translated into Spanish, but I'm not sure about short-stay Schengen visas.

Where are you applying from? What did your local Visa Application Centre / consulate / embassy say when you asked them?
